# How to use firebase collection length in list view builder flutter null safety

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart

I am relatively new to flutter and firebase and trying to rtrieve messages from a collection of messages, each having message properties like message text, sender etc.
however, when using list view builder, I can't use itemcount as it says, Future cant be used in place of int or 'data can't be unconditionally called as it may be null'. Adding null check (!) causes it to say that it can't be used for object. please help.

```
void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Firebase.initializeApp();
  runApp(MaterialApp(
      home: readMessage(),
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      theme: ThemeData(
        brightness: Brightness.dark,
        primarySwatch: Colors.purple,
      )));
}

class readMessage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() {
    return _readMessageState();
  }
}

class _readMessageState extends State<readMessage> {
  bool isMe = true;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return StreamBuilder(
        stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance
            .collection('users')
            .doc('ItpNRR6uNfl4Mf4qvlIa')
            .collection('messages')
            .snapshots(),
        builder: ((context, snapshot) {
          /// This is where I need the listview builder of collection inside the document
        }));
  }

  BoxDecoration messageBubbleMaker(bool isMe){
    return BoxDecoration(
      borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(topRight: Radius.circular(20), topLeft: Radius.circular(20), bottomRight: isMe? Radius.zero : Radius.circular(20), bottomLeft: !isMe? Radius.zero : Radius.circular(20)),
      color: isMe? Colors.black : Colors.blueAccent
    );
  }
}
```

This is my code.

`it supports null safety`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your stream you need to convert each snapshot from json to an object and then convert it to a list. Then, you can use `snapshot.data.length` as the `itemcount` in your `ListView.builder`. For example,

```
 return StreamBuilder(
            stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance
                .collection('users')
                .doc('ItpNRR6uNfl4Mf4qvlIa')
                .collection('messages')
                .snapshots().map((snapshot) =>
                    snapshot.docs.map((doc) => Message.fromJson(doc.data())).toList()),
            builder: ((context, snapshot) {
              ListView.builder(
                itemCount: snapshot.data.length,
                itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                  // return something for every item in the list
                }),
            }));
```

And have a model class for messages called message.dart. For example:

```
class Message {
  final String messageId;
  final String content;

  Message(this.messageId, this.content);

  Message.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json)
      : messageId = json['messageId'],
        content = json['content'];

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        'messageId': messageId,
        'content': content,
      };
}
```

Comment: map((snapshot) =>
                    snapshot.docs.map((doc) => Messages.fromJson(doc.data())).toList())

What does it do?

Comment: Messages.fromJson. What is Messages?

Comment: You must have a model class Message.dart with all the document fields of 'messages' collection in flutter. This class will also have two functions, one for getting the data from Json (i.e. from firestore) and another one for mapping it and storing to firestore. Thus, Message.fromJson is a function to convert your documents from json for reading in flutter. While you have to do it for messages, an example for doing it for users can be found here: https://flutter.dev/docs/development/data-and-backend/json

Comment: I have added a sample model class for messages in the answer

Comment: i am new and don't get the models. I am still learning. Can you explain where the Messages.fromJson came as there is no definition for it

Comment: There is no official definition for Message.fromJson. It is a user-defined function that you must write to convert the data you get from firestore to something we can use in the flutter app. Since data is stored in the form of Json (a data format) in firestore, when we get the messages documents from firestore, we use the function that we defined, Message.fromJson to convert from json to usable form.

Answer (score 0):

This works

```
StreamBuilder(
          stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance
              .collection('collection name')
              .doc('doc id')
              .collection('collection name')
              .snapshots();
```

Gets a collection as QuerySnapshot (data type).
If you are using a document, then it will be a DocumentSnapshot instead of querySnapshot

Now in the builder

```
builder: ((context, snapshot) {
    if (snapshot.hasData) {
      var collectionData = snapshot.data as QuerySnapshot;
    }
```

This will check presence of data and optional but recommended.

You can define the collectionData without if statement or add using the ? interpolation like

```
snapshot.hasData ? <What to do if true> : <what to do if false>
```

In listview builder inside the same if statement above:

```
itemCount: messages.docs.length,
itembuilder: (BuildContext context, int index)
                          {
                            var collectionDataList = collectionData.docs.toList();
                            var CollectionDoc = collectionDataList[index];
                            return Text(CollectionDoc['field name']);
                          })
```

Replace the Text field with anything you like, like a custom message bubble maker for a chat app where you can provide the field values as parameters.